# Pyspark submit master yarn cluster deploy - logs location

Tags: pyspark

I submitted pyspark job with spark-submit command on a haddoop cluster. The command is as follows

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 1g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 2 --py-files module_stm_extracts.py,module_table_compare.py datacheck,py
```

The job completed, but I never got the application id in the console.
How do I find the application log, so that I can review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it at the YARN Resource Manager WebUI, by default it's acessible through the 8088 port of the master node: `http://<master_node_ip>:8088`

Or you can list the applications through command line too:

```
yarn application -list -appStates ALL
```

And with the applicationId get the log with the following command:

```
yarn logs --applicationId <application_id>
```